# Text and Symbol unaligned in input value

Tags: html

I am trying to add matrial-icon right chevron symbol to `<input type="button">` using the right chevron unicode. Now the text in the button and the symbol are not aligned.
How can I fix it?
For some reason, I don't have access to HTML and CSS. I can use javascript and jQuery to do it.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="button" class="material-icons" onclick="javascript:alert('hello')" id="InsertButton" title="Submit" value="SUBMIT &#x85cc" >
```

And this is the output:
[image]

Also I want to give text as 'Submit' instead of 'SUBMIT'. Small alphabets are not visible here.

Comment: input{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center} use this styling

Comment: No this is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all the HTML code for **>** is **&#62**.
Try setting `line-height`

```css
.btn{
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0;
} 
   }
```

```html
<input type="button" class="material-icons btn" onclick="javascript:alert('hello')" id="InsertButton" title="Submit" value="SUBMIT &#62" >
```

Answer (score 0):

For lower case first break your string like

```
string.substr(0,1).toUppercase(). string.substr(1,)toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Right chevron symbol 'Submit ❯'.It will work in IE too.